# Getting the value of <button> using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter and as much as possible i don't want to use the $_GET method. What are the other ways to get the value of a button tag?

Here's my button code:

```
<button id="first" name="first" type="submit" value="Php3000"></button>
```

I just want to get the value of the button to be able to pass it to my controller.

I am a beginner, please enlighten me. Thank you.

**EDIT**

Sorry for not making it clear to you guys, actually i have three buttons

```
 <button id="first" name="first" type="submit" value="Php3000"></button>                
 <button id="second" name="second" type="submit" value="Php2000"></button>              
 <button id="third" name="third" type="submit" value="Php2500"></button>
```

The user must choose among those three buttons and I should get the value of the chosen button.

Example of what i want to do : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button_value2

There it displayed the value of the button, i want to get it and pass it to my controller

Comment: If not `GET` then `POST` or `REQUEST`. Other than that, you're plum outta luck.

Comment: Why not a hidden field? Why a button?

Comment: Hmm the user must choose so hidden field is not an option

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 I already tried it but it's not working for me :(

Comment: @TerraSova A radio button? A checkbox?

Comment: @DamienPirsy I have edited now my question, sorry for not making it clear

Comment: @DamienPirsy just a regular button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use form helper:

```
<?php echo_form('c=controller&m=method'); ?>
```

then instead of buttons:

```
<button id="first" name="first" type="submit" value="Php3000"></button>                
<button id="second" name="second" type="submit" value="Php2000"></button>              
<button id="third" name="third" type="submit" value="Php2500"></button>
```

try to use inputs:

```
<input id="first" name="first" type="submit" value="Php3000">                
<input id="second" name="second" type="submit" value="Php2000">              
<input id="third" name="third" type="submit" value="Php2500">
```

then close your form:

```
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

in your controller method try:

```
if(isset($this->input->post('first'))){
   $first = $this->input->post('first');
}
```

or just this one:

```
if($this->input->post('first')){
   $first = $this->input->post('first');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the additional answer..

HTML Buttons in forms are treated as input fields, but only the value of the pressed button will actually be submitted.

So you should rewrite your buttons as follows or similiar:

```
<button id="first" name="selected_button" value="Php3000">Choose php 3000 label</button>                
<button id="second" name="selected_button" value="Php2000">Choose php 2000 label</button>              
<button id="third" name="selected_button" value="Php2500">Choose php 2500 label</button>
```

The value of the selected button will then be available as $_POST['selected_button'], or in CodeIgniter

```
$selected_button = $this->input->post('selected_button');

switch($selected_button){ ... }
```

If you give your buttons separate names you will have to check each one, but like this you can just get get the value, and decide how to go on from there. In that aspect Buttons are also much more developer-friendly than Inputs of type submit.

I would not rely on javascript if it's not guaranteed to be available on all client machines. Although it's a nice way of doing it.

Edit: If you are using some fancy CSS you wouldn't even have to rely on buttons/forms but could use links directly. Assuming you'd be using the pretty twitter bootstrap, it might look as follows:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/method/Php3000'); ?>" class="btn btn-info">Choose php 3000 label</a>
...
```

If you don't need any additional data submitted at the same time, this approach would have the least overhead.

Answer (score 0):

you can always find the value of the button using javascript and then pass it to a separate PHP file via an AJAX call.

If you are using JQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
JQuery.post( "backend.php",
    $("first").val(),
    function(data) {
       //do something here on success.
    });
```

and in the backend we can handle in CodeIgniter in the backend.php file, and send instructions back to the running webpage.  Is this not what you were attempting to do?

Comment: Unfortuantely, i am not using JQuery :( I still have to learn about it

Comment: That's all the code is required. On the back end, proceed as normal: If the form is submitted -> what is the value of button ID "first". echo $_POST['first'];

Comment: @TerraSova, you don't need JQuery to do this, a javascript-only example of using AJAX can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use CodeIgniter, but according to http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html you should be able to just grab the values from the input handler inside your controller:

```
if( $this->input->post('first') ) { // First button was pressed; }
```